# Getting multiple matches from regex pattern in Python

Tags: python, regex, escaping, backslash, backreference

I'm writing a regular expression to parse arguments in a fashion similar to shell arguments, with spaces and quoted strings as the delimiters, as well as backslash escaping. This seems to work on [RegexPal](http://regexpal.com/):

```
(?:(["'])(?:\\(?:\\\\)?\1|\\\\|.)*?\1|(?:\\(?:\\\\)?\s|\\\\|\S)+)
```

Here is a more readable version of that:

```
(?:(["'])(?:        # Match a double or single quote followed by
     \\(?:\\\\)?\1  #   an odd number of backslashes, then the same quote
    |\\\\           #   or two backslashes
    |.              #   or anything else  
    )*?\1           # any number of times (lazily) followed by the same quote,
|(?:                # OR
     \\(?:\\\\)?\s  #   an odd number of backslashes, then whitespace
    |\\\\           #   or two backslashes
    |\S             #   or any non-whitespace
 )+                 # any number of times.
)
```

I've tried putting this into Python with re.findall, but the output is nonsense:

```
>>> re.findall(
... r"(?:([\"'])(?:\\(?:\\\\)?\1|\\\\|.)*?\1|(?:\\(?:\\\\)?\s|\\\\|\S)+)",
... r'the quick brown\ fox jumps "over the" lazy\\ dog')
['', '', '', '', '"', '', '']
```

RegexPal, on the other hand, shows the correct result:

```
[the] [quick] [brown\ fox] [jumps] ["over the"] [lazy\\] [dog]
```

Am I forgetting to format the pattern a certain way for Python? Or does Python interpret regex differently in some way? I have no idea why the only non-empty match would be a double-quote, and I've confirmed that the pattern itself works the way it should.

Comment: The shlex module might be of interest to you.

Comment: I started with the shlex module when I was writing this code, but I've found that it's not flexible enough for my purposes. I need to be able to split the arguments apart and preserve any surrounding quotes, backslashes, and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like everything is inside a non-capturing group.  So you get matches, just no matching content.

Comment: I tried making the outermost group capturing, but that breaks the internal backreferences. If you know of a way to fix that (I've tried changing `\1` to `\2`, to no avail), I'm all ears.

Comment: @Fraxtil, the backreferences are numbered by the opening brackets. The first opening bracket is `\1`, the second is `\2` ... .

Comment: I'm not sure why it didn't work the first time, but I removed the leading `?:` and substituted `\2` for `\1` again, and it works flawlessly this time. Thank you!